# Realm.insertOrUpdate and copyToOrUpdate don't work, but createObject does

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a list of Events which I'm trying to save like so:

My Event Class:

```
public class Event extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private long id;

private String title;
private Date eventStart;
//some more ints and strings
}
```

insert/copy

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        // This doesn't work and exits the method entirely
        realm.insertOrUpdate(events);

        // This doesn't work and exits the method entirely
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(events.get(0));

        // This workaround works but only if there are no duplicates, or primary keys
        for (Event event: events) {
            Event realmEvent = realm.createObject(Event.class, event.getId());
            realmEvent.setTitle(event.getTitle());
            realmEvent.setEventState(event.getEventStart());
        }
    }
});
```

with some classes, copyToRealm works, and others they don't.

I stepped through the code in debug mode and noticed that in generated DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java, it does not seem to recognize the RealmObject I give it as the correct RealmObject. It gets to this part:

```
@Override
public void insertOrUpdate(Realm realm, Collection<? extends RealmModel> objects) {
Iterator<? extends RealmModel> iterator = objects.iterator();
    RealmModel object = null;
    Map<RealmModel, Long> cache = new HashMap<RealmModel, Long>(objects.size());
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Class<RealmModel> clazz = (Class<RealmModel>) ((object instanceof RealmObjectProxy) ? object.getClass().getSuperclass() : object.getClass());

    if (clazz.equals(com.example.models.Event.class)) {
        io.realm.EventRealmProxy.insertOrUpdate(realm, (com.example.models.Event) object, cache);
    } else {
        throw getMissingProxyClassException(clazz);
    }
```

and then it evaluates to false and throws that exception, as if the Event.class I'm passing to it is not actually an Event.class object.
But the debugger lists the clazz object as com.example.models.Event.

The exception is "RealmObject is not part of the schema for this Realm"

My Project level gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.4.0"
}
```

My app level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
... //rest of dependencies etc.

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: Saw a similar issue [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3139) but no solutions there work for me.

Comment: Well what is the exception? And what is your plugin order in your gradle? What is your build tools version?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: It sounds like our annotation processor isn't running for some reason. If you check the gradle log, do you see something like `Note: Processing Event` ?

Comment: :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavacNote: Processing class OtherClass

Note: Processing class Event

Note: Creating DefaultRealmModule

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Guess I need to check that out as well.

Comment: Do you have only one `Event`? Is it possible that you have multiple `Event` classes in different packages? is the `event` an instance of child class of `Event`?